# Cómo saber cuáles y cuántos números se repiten en c#?

Tags: c#

Buenas quería saber como puedo hacer que mi programa sepa cuántos números se repiten y cuáles. Ya lo he intentado pero no me ha dado. Este es mi código. Se los agradecería mucho. Gracias

```
 int num;
 int entrada = Convert.ToInt16(Interaction.InputBox("¿Cuantos numeros vas a ingresar?", "Numeros"));
 for (int t = 0; t < entrada; t++)
 {
     num = Convert.ToInt16(Interaction.InputBox("Ingrese el numero" + (t + 1)));
     listBox1.Items.Add(num);
     int[] lista = new int[num];


     for (int i = 0; i < lista.Length; i++)
     {
         lista[i] += 1;
     }
     for (int j = 0; j < lista.Length; j++)
     {
         listBox2.Items.Add("Se repite el numero" + j + ":" + lista[j]);

     }
 }
```

Comment: Supongo que es una tarea escolar. Si es así, habéis dado ya los diccionarios? LINQ?

Comment: se puede hacer sin diccionarios, pero con foreach y varias listas, o una lista de listas, te suena el foreach?

Answer (score 0):

En tu codigo hay varias cosas incorrectas, pero la principal es la inicializacion del array, tal como lo has puesto esta creando un array de tamaño `num` nuevo en cada iteracion cuando lo que tienes que hacer es añadir cada nuevo numero al array. Tambien veo que no hay ninguna comprobacion para ver si el numero ya existe en el array.

Se puede hacer de maneras mas eficientes, pero modificando tu codigo lo minimo para que funcione quedaria asi:

```
int num;

int entrada = Convert.ToInt16(Interaction.InputBox("¿Cuantos numeros vas a ingresar?", "Numeros"));
int[] lista = new int[entrada];

for (int t = 0; t < entrada; t++)
{
    num = Convert.ToInt16(Interaction.InputBox("Ingrese el numero" + (t + 1)));
    listBox1.Items.Add(num);
    lista[t] = num;

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        if (lista[i] == num)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add("Se repite el numero" + (i+1) + " : " + lista[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Basicamente, los cambios introducidos son:

- Crear un array de tamaño `entrada` antes del bucle
- Añadir cada numero introducido al array
- Recorrer el array hasta `t-1` para comprobar si el numero ya existe